# An algorithm to find the set of numbers which matches the fewest numbers in a collection of set of equivalent numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, math, set

If I have (for example, the actual dataset is *much* larger)

A collection of lists of 4 numbers picked from 0-9:

- (1,2,3,4)
- (3,5,6,0)
- (4,5,7,9)
- (1,2,7,8)

And want to find the list(s) of numbers with fewest matches that could exist against the collection, is there a good algorithmic approach?

In the above example it might be (1,6,7,2), which matches just one in 3 cases and 2 in the last case

Comment: what do you mean by "fewest matches"? What's your measure for number of matches?

Comment: @Primusa have added some clarification in the question, but the number of elements the sets have in common

Comment: Rewording it, how can I find the set with the smallest intersection with all sets in a collection

Comment: What is a strict algorithmic definition? Would `sum(len(candidiate & s) for s in sets)` be accurate? Also note that sets don't have duplicates, so are all the elements in each of your lists unique?

Comment: Yes, sorry, all the elements are unique.

Comment: That code would get me the set with the lowest total matches, but could still be 1 complete match and the rest null matches, for example, whereas I'm looking for the set that matches least overall (ie one that, say, never manages to match more than 2 elements in a set). Think of it as the least lucky set of lottery numbers if that makes more sense

Comment: In your question you have tuples, not sets. So let's say we have `data = [(1,2,3,4), (3,5,6,0), (4,5,7,9), (1,2,7,8)]`. With `min(len({1, 6, 7, 2}.intersection(set(element))) for element in data)` you would get the count of fewest matches. Now you can loop over the data to find which elements match this result.

Comment: @Felix if that is the case then what is your metric to calculate the number of matches? Would it be `max(len(candidiate & s) for s in sets)`?

Comment: Thanks, and perhaps I should be clearer here; finding the intersection isn't the tough bit, what I'm hoping to avoid doing is looping over every possible set to find the candidate with fewest matches across the test collection

Comment: There are only `210` possible candidates though? No?

Comment: The above is an example, the actual conditions are a set of 6 unique numbers between 0 and 99, matching against about 5000 sets

Comment: @Felix I understand that finding the intersection isn't the tough the part. The issue is that once I understand what metric you are using to define closeness (right now it feels arbitrary) I can actually try and figure out how to find the "closest"

Comment: I think your second metric is what OP means @Primusa the correct candidate is any that minimizes the max number of matches in a given `s`.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do this without scoring every candidate - I can think of no greedy approach that would get the right solution

Comment: That's the conclusion I've reached too, I think I'm just going to have to build the slow code and find out just how slow it is before I run to AWS. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Felix hold on, imagine we sort every list and build a trie on each set and every subset of that set. That's 5000 * 2^6 nodes in the trie which is fine. Then the question becomes find the shallowest path in the trie, which can be solved in `O(N)`. Let me know if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: Your example analysis seems wrong. The matches seem to be: `{1,2}, {6}, {7}, {1,2,7}`. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Clarifications must be edited into the question, not left in comments alone.  Your problem statement is still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Really simple approach using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

sets = [[1,2,3,4],[3,5,6,0],[4,5,7,9],[1,2,7,8]]

numbers, counts = np.unique(sets, return_counts=True)

candidate = numbers[np.argsort(counts)[:np.size(sets, axis=1)]]

print(candidate)
# [0 6 8 9]
```

Comment: Seems finding candidates this way only uses numbers that are in variable sets.  If we change to: sets = [[1,2,3,4],[3,5,6,1],[4,5,7,9],[1,2,7,8]] (so 0 no longer in sets), the solved candidate is: [6 8 9 2].  But [6 8 9 0] for instance has fewer overall matches.  Note: we can select any four unique numbers from 0-9 from the question comments.